# Using a factory inside another factory AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory, angularjs-module

I have a module...

```
angular.module('myModule', []);
```

And then a factory

```
angular.module('myModule')
.factory('factory1', [
  function() {
    //some var's and functions
}
]);
```

And then another factory

```
angular.module('myModule')
.factory('factory2', [
  function() {
    //some var's and functions BUT I want to use some var's from factory1
}
]);
```

But I want to use some variables from factory1 inside factory2, how can I inject factory1 into factory2?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is what I would do:

**On Factory One**

```
angular.module('sampleApp')
    .factory('factory1', function() {
        var factory1 = {};

        factory1.method1 = function () {
            return true;
        };

        factory1.method2 = function () {
            return "hello";
        };

        return factory1;
    }
);
```

**On Factory Two**

```
angular.module('sampleApp')
    .factory('factory2', ['factory1',
        function(factory1) {

            var factory2 = {};

            factory2.method3 = function () {
                return "bye vs " + factory1.method2();
            };

            return factory2;
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks @MohammadSepahvand nice addition.

Comment: Yeah, It is great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i did and worked fine. Call SessionPresenters from Session

```
angular.module('tryme3App')
    .factory('Session', function ($resource, DateUtils, SessionPresenters) {
        return $resource('api/sessions/:id', {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);

                    var result = SessionPresenters.get({id: data.id})
                    data.presenters = result; 
                    return data;
                }
            },
            'update': { method:'PUT' }
        });
    }).factory('SessionPresenters', function ($resource, DateUtils) {
        return $resource('api/session.Presenters/:id', {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'get': {
                method: 'GET', isArray: true
            },
            'update': { method:'PUT' }
        });
    });
```